# Salesforce Communities license in sandbox

Tags: community

Our client has community licenses purchases in production.But i cannot see that in sandbox.

To get communities in sandbox available do i need to refresh sandbox?

If i do that,is there a way to protect my metadata,data in sandbox?

or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 7):

ATTENTION: To future readers finding this as a search result, the answers here are outdated.

You can now update license counts from production without refreshing your sandbox: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335272&type=1

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the correct/easiest way to get licenses from production to sandbox is to do a refresh - you'll get your licenses.

If you have metadata in your sandbox that you don't want to lose, just use something like Ant, Eclipse, or Changesets to save it locally or move it to a different environment when you do your refresh and then copy it back. (If you don't have a process for already doing this, I strongly urge you to look into the Ant Force.com Migration Toolkit - it's worth it.)

If for some reason you can't or won't do that, you can try to file a case with Salesforce to activate your licenses in your sandbox. It's been a long time since I've done that so can't speak to how easy/hard that is these days.

Comment: "Easy" is really hit-and-miss with salesforce.com these days. The Ant/Force.com IDE backup-refresh-deploy solution is the most reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to refresh from prod to make any license available in sandbox .One way to protect your data and metadata is create another sandbox and move all config and data there .

Data you can also export it through import wizard or data loader and keep in your local disk.For metadata you can use eclipse to take back up or push into some developer org or some other sandbox

Answer (score 1):

The only way to synchronize the licenses with production is to refresh the sandbox.
To preserve your data, you can create a new sandbox and then just deploy the changes from one sandbox to the new sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Above comments are correct.  I had to do exactly this back in June.  The only way was to refresh the Sandbox.